# Read files owned by root from a container

Tags: docker, filebeat

I have a Docker container (call it A) which creates log files on the host. Since the user running in the container is root the logs are also owned by root. Now I want a Filebeat container to read those logs.

I can think of the following options:

1. Rebuild container A and make sure its user is non-root. I'm
   reluctant to do this since the container is quite complicated.
2. Add
   the Filebeat user to the root group. Seems like a bad idea from a
   security point of view and would make the application less portable
   as I'd have to do the same for every host.

Is there an easier option I might be overlooking?

Comment: does it create a new log file or does it append to existing logs?

Comment: It does both. Is there a difference to the way I could handle it if it only did one?

Comment: Yes there is, if the log file already exists on the host appending the new log data to the log will not change the permissions. Therefor if you set the permissions correctly on the host it does not matter that the application writes to it as root. But this does not apply to newly created files

Comment: Making a Docker image that runs as non-root shouldn't be tricky: `RUN adduser` of some flavor depending on the base image, then add a `USER` directive towards the end of the `Dockerfile`.  This is frequently a recommended setup (and not-so-frequently actually done).